# DoesNotExist on django

Tags: django

Could somebody help please? I try to play videos on my site but it seems I have some problem. I am a beginner in Python and Django.

Here is what's shown to me:

> ['DoesNotExist', 'MultipleObjectsReturned', '**class**',
> '**delattr**', '**dict**', '**dir**', '**doc**', '**eq**',
> '**format**', '**ge**', '**getattribute**', '**getstate**', '**gt**',
> '**hash**', '**init**', '**init_subclass**', '**le**', '**lt**',
> '**module**', '**ne**', '**new**', '**reduce**', '**reduce_ex**',
> '**repr**', '**setattr**', '**setstate**', '**sizeof**', '**str**',
> '**subclasshook**', '**weakref**', '_check_column_name_clashes',
> '_check_constraints', '_check_field_name_clashes', '_check_fields',
> '_check_id_field', '_check_index_together', '_check_indexes',
> '_check_local_fields', '_check_long_column_names',
> '_check_m2m_through_same_relationship', '_check_managers',
> '_check_model', '_check_model_name_db_lookup_clashes',
> '_check_ordering',
> '_check_property_name_related_field_accessor_clashes',
> '_check_single_primary_key', '_check_swappable',
> '_check_unique_together', '_do_insert', '_do_update',
> '_get_FIELD_display', '_get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD',
> '_get_next_or_previous_in_order', '_get_pk_val', '_get_unique_checks',
> '_meta', '_perform_date_checks', '_perform_unique_checks',
> '_save_parents', '_save_table', '_set_pk_val', '_state', 'check',
> 'clean', 'clean_fields', 'comment_set', 'date_error_message',
> 'datetime', 'delete', 'description', 'from_db', 'full_clean',
> 'get_deferred_fields', 'get_next_by_datetime',
> 'get_previous_by_datetime', 'id', 'objects', 'path', 'pk',
> 'prepare_database_save', 'refresh_from_db', 'save', 'save_base',
> 'serializable_value', 'title', 'unique_error_message', 'user',
> 'user_id', 'validate_unique'] XZZ4ROG1UHRoute_Montélimar.mp4 user
> signed in <QuerySet []> [21/Sep/2020 06:11:43] "GET /video/24
> HTTP/1.1" 200 966

my code is:

```
class VideoFileView(View):
    
    def get(self, request, file_name):
        BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
        print(BASE_DIR)
        file = FileWrapper(open(BASE_DIR+'/'+file_name, 'rb'))
        response = HttpResponse(file, content_type='video/mp4')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}'.format(file_name)
        return response

class VideoView(View):
    template_name = 'video.html'

    def get(self, request, id):
        #fetch video from DB by ID
        video_by_id = Video.objects.get(id=id)
        BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
        print(dir(video_by_id))
        print(video_by_id.path)
        video_by_id.path = BASE_DIR+'/'+video_by_id.path 
        context = {'video':video_by_id}
          
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            print('user signed in')
            comment_form = CommentForm()
            context['form'] = comment_form

        
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(video__id=id).order_by('-datetime')[:5]
        print(comments)
        context['comments'] = comments
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

Comment: we need to see your code too.

Comment: what does not exist on django?

Comment: well you passed the video to your template, that's good. But it would be handy to see how the model and template looks like too

Answer (score 0):

#So did I for the next step:

class VideoView(View):
template_name = 'video.html'

```
def get(self, request, id):
    #fetch video from DB by ID
    video_by_id = Video.objects.get(id=id)
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    video_by_id.path = 'http://localhost:8000/get_video/'+video_by_id.path
    context = {'video':video_by_id}
    
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        print('user signed in')
        comment_form = CommentForm()
        context['form'] = comment_form

    
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(video__id=id).order_by('-datetime')[:5]
    print(comments)
    context['comments'] = comments
    return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

#The terminal server show me:
Not Found:/get_video/ ...

Comment: please, we need to see how your model and template looks like. Dont post your code as an answer, just update the question.